# Computing the matrix of a Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, definition

For a matrix $A\in M_n(\mathbb{F})$ consider the
linear transformation $T_A:\mathbb{F}^n\rightarrow
\mathbb{F}^n$. Denote the $B_{st}=\{e_1,...,e_n\}$
the standard basis of $\mathbb{F}^n.$

Compute the matrix $[T_A]_{B_{st}}$.

---

So I don't really want anyone to solve the problem for me. I'm posting this because I do not understand whats being asked for in the problem.

So I know $A\in M_n(\mathbb{F})$ means that $A$ is
an $n\times n$ matrix with $\mathbb{F}$-valued entries.
I was taught that every linear transformation $T:V\rightarrow V$ has an associated matrix $[T]_B\in M_n(\mathbb{F})$ which "mirrors" the transformation in $\mathbb{F}^n$ with respect to basis $B$. But I don't
understand what $T_A$ is in this problem.

Is it just denoting that $A$ is a linear transformation? Also, if $T_A$ is a map from $\mathbb{F}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{F}^n$, then what is
$[T_A]_{B_{st}}$? I was taught that $[\cdot]_{B_{st}}$ is a coordinate map from $V\rightarrow \mathbb{F}^n$ where if $x\in V$ and $x=a_1e_1+...+a_ne_n \mapsto 
(a_1,...,a_n)\in \mathbb{F}^n$. But if $T_A$ is a matrix already I don't know what $[\cdot]_{B_{st}}$
is doing.

Any help with understanding is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map $T_A$ is$$\begin{array}{rccc}T_A\colon&\mathbb{F}^n&\longrightarrow&\mathbb{F}^n\\&v&\mapsto&Av.\end{array}$$

Comment: Is there a reason why we don't just denote the map as $A:\mathbb{F}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{F}^n$? Is it a similar reason for why we wouldn't say $2x:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ but instead write $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $x\mapsto 2x$?

Comment: Concerning your first question, it is because $A$ is a matrix, not a map. The second question is unrelated. If you wish, post it as another question.

Comment: The second question was asking if it was a good analogy for why we don’t denote the map as A.

Comment: Got it! But no, I do not think that it is a good analogy. In $2x$, the $x$ is a generice real number. There is nothing similar in the cases of $A$. It *would* be similar if your suggestion was to represent the map by $A.v$.

Answer (score 0):

$T_A:\mathbb{F}^n\rightarrow
\mathbb{F}^n$ is given by $T_Ax=Ax$ for $x \in \mathbb{F}^n.$ Since $B_{st}$ is the standard basis, we have $[T_A]_{B_{st}}=A$.

Comment: Does this mean that if I have another basis $\mathcal{C}$, then $[T_A]_{\mathcal{C}}$ is like the representation of $A$ with respect to the basis $\mathcal{C}$? Also, when it states that $B_{st}$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb{F}^n$, is $B_{st}$ a subset of $\mathbb{F}^n$? Because I normally think of a basis as being a subset of a vector space $V$ as oppose to $\mathbb{F}$.